# regex для строки js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, link

подскажите пожалуйста как при помощи регулярки вырезать `id` поста, а именно 16011 из ссылки типа:  `/wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_save_as_new_post&post=16011&_wpnonce=bc80ec66ff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
(?<=post=)\d+
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5bc09

> http://skolerom.loc/wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_save_as_new_post&post=**16011**&_wpnonce=bc80ec66ff
>
> /wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_save_as_new_post&post=**16011**&_wpnonce=bc80ec66ff

Сгенерированный код:

```js
const regex = /(?<=post=)\d+/gm;
const str = `http://skolerom.loc/wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_save_as_new_post&post=16011&_wpnonce=bc80ec66ff
/wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_save_as_new_post&post=16011&_wpnonce=bc80ec66ff`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Та за шо минус?

Comment: А кто-то ходит и по пиколу их жмёт. Мне тоже влепили.

Answer (score 2):

Я вот так вижу. Но у ответа выше решение красивее и быстрее, я думаю.

```js
const regexp = /&post=[\d]+/;

const str = 'http://skolerom.loc/wp-admin/admin.php?action=duplicate_post_save_as_new_post&post=16011&_wpnonce=bc80ec66ff';

let resultId = str.match(regexp)[0].match(/\d+/)[0];

console.log(resultId);
```

Comment: `console.log( str.match(/&post=(\d+)/)[1] );` - называется "Группа захвата" ) `[1]-й` элемент в возвращаемом массиве - тот самый `(\d+)`. Можно перестраховаться на случай отсутствия post, `console.log( ( str.match(/&post=(\d+)/) || [0,0] )[1] );`